# How to compare two data frames and drop those rows appearing in 2nd data frame "knock out list" using dplyr()?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'd like to stick with `dplyr()` if possible (I'm a major fan), or base R is fine too if the solution is simple.

Suppose you have two data frames, as shown below. I'd like to create a new data frame that compares the two (`df1` and `df2`), and only shows those complete rows from `df1` whose ID doesn't appear in the ID's shown in `df2`. `df2` serves as the "knock out" list. How would this be done?

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1,2,3,4,5),
  Value = c(10,20,30,40,50)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  ID = c(6,7,8,1,2),
  Value = c(60,70,80,10,20)
)
```

The new data frame, call it `df3`, would look like this after applying the `df2` "knock outs", when run in the R studio console:

```
  ID Value
1  3    30
2  4    40
3  5    50
```

ID's 1 and 2 got knocked out because they appear in both `df1` and `df2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be achieved via an `anti_join`:

```r
dplyr::anti_join(df1, df2, by = "ID")
#>   ID Value
#> 1  3    30
#> 2  4    40
#> 3  5    50
```

Comment: I knew dplyr() would have an elegant function for this! And I won't forget a name like "anti_join"! Quick question: does putting "dplyr::" at the beginning help in any way, other than denoting that this is a dplyr function?

Comment: It depends. (: Here I simply used it for brevity. Personally I use the `::` notation in cases where I only need one or two functions from a package or when I need a function only once in a script or when I use functions inside my own packages or when I want to avoid nameclashes . In general when using `::` you have a small loss in performance. However, attaching a whole package also involves some one-time overhead. Hence there is a trade-off.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comments. The answer of stefan is best. Here is an alternative with Base `R`:

```
df1[!(df1$ID %in% df2$ID),]
```

```
  ID Value
3  3    30
4  4    40
5  5    50
```

benchmark:
[image]